# Why argument lost value after passing to another function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, parameter-passing

I'm using TypeScript 2 and Angular 2.
After the argument (`idAttr`) was lost value and became NaN.
The code is below:

```
addRow(event) {
    const target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
    console.log(idAttr);
    this.addItem(+idAttr, "ewewe");
}

addItem(index:number, title:string): void {
    let item = new Register10SectionViewModel();
    item.SectionTitle = title;
    item.SectionId = +index;
    item.AssetType = "test";
    item.CauseDisposal = null;
    item.Num1 = 0;
    item.Num2 = 0;
    item.Num3 = 0;
    item.Num4 = 0;
    this.model.Register10Data = [...this.model.Register10Data, item];
}
```

`addRow(event)` it is event that's bind to button in loop

```
<button (click)="addRow($event)" style="float: right" id="{{data1.id}}">+</button>
```

In debug i see that's `idAttr` has valid value in `addRow` but in `addItem` argument became with NaN value. Why? Do I declare idAttr as a global variable?=)

Comment: Actually it's not lost. The `+` operator tries to change the variable value into number and since that variable isn't 'numberish', it returns `NaN`.

Comment: What is the value of `idAttr` in `addRow`? If it's not a number(ish), it's like that `+idAttr` tries for force it into a number, but can't, so it just becomes NaN ("not a number").

Comment: Yes. It's works when I'm using `idAttr.value`. But why `console.log(idAttr);` returns actual value? Function `log` parses argument and looks for an attribute "value"?